# Filter using Java Stream == > a HashMap of custom objects to a HashSet

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream, hashset

How do I filter Hashmap of two custom objects to filter and stream and collect onto an map --->  Map<String, String>

In specific example below, how does one filter by Mortgage type to obtain one mortgage type with minimum rate (lowest interest %).

Please help in my using pictures to conceptualize the structures of what I have on a MS Excel sheet and attempt to represent onto Java code.

It’s easier for me to conceptualize using pictures.  Chart below is what I actually have on the MS Excel, however I am not sure if I have to code correct.

[image]

Let’s say for instance in this scenario, I wish to create a HashSet and filter by house type and obtain the houses with lowest interest rate, irrespective of term and loanID; meaning disregarding term and loanID.
(For sake of brevity, all data types are string.  Still sortable).

In instance above, the desired and expected output should be a HashSet containing the green-highlighted values.

[image]

Final desired output.

[image]

How can I do this via Streams, Java 8,9,10,11.

Please see code here at github.  ((I am learning using github, please let me know if anything’s needed.)) Please advise.  Thank you.

[https://github.com/user2021/Learning-HashMap-to-HashSet-streams/blob/main/src/Loans_Packages/Main.java](https://github.com/user2021/Learning-HashMap-to-HashSet-streams)

```
package Loans_Packages;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<List<Mortgage>, List<Document>> Loan_Contracts = new HashMap<>();

        List<Mortgage> houses = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Document> terms = new ArrayList<>();

        Mortgage mortgageObject0 = new Mortgage("WOOD", "15-YR");
        houses.add(mortgageObject0);
        Mortgage mortgageObject1 = new Mortgage("WOOD", "30-YR");
        houses.add(mortgageObject1);
        Mortgage mortgageObject2 = new Mortgage("BRICK", "30-YR");
        houses.add(mortgageObject2);
        Mortgage mortgageObject3 = new Mortgage("BRICK", "15-YR");
        houses.add(mortgageObject3);

        Document loanObject0 = new Document("5A", "Interest_5.0%");
        terms.add(loanObject0);
        Document loanObject1 = new Document("5B", "Interest_3.5%");
        terms.add(loanObject1);
        Document loanObject2 = new Document("5C", "Interest_3.5%");
        terms.add(loanObject2);
        Document loanObject3 = new Document("5D", "Interest_1.5%");
        terms.add(loanObject3);

        
        
        Loan_Contracts.put(houses, terms);
        System.out.println(Loan_Contracts);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();


//        System.out.println();
//        Map<String, String> filteredHouses = Loan_Contracts.entrySet()
//                .stream()
//                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue())
//                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().get(0)));
        //.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get the point to map a list of mortgages to a list of documents, in this way you have that all mortgages are mapped to all documents, losing the one to one association between them

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, `Loan_Contracts` map does not need to have `List` as key / value.  It would be sufficient to use `Mortgage` as key and `Document` as value, thus they form a `Map.Entry` representing a row.

Then a new map may be created like this from the `houses` and `terms` lists:

```java
Map<Mortgage, Document> Loan_Contracts = IntStream.range(0, houses.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(houses.get(i), terms.get(i)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Then the houses filtered by type with the minimal rate can be retrieved like this:

```java
Loan_Contracts.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getType(),
                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().getRate()))
        ))
.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("type=%s, %s%n", 
        k, v.map(Map.Entry::getValue).orElse(null)));
```

Output:

```
type=WOOD, Document(loanId=5B, rate=Interest_3.5%)
type=BRICK, Document(loanId=5D, rate=Interest_1.5%)
```

Comment: Or a single `IntStream.range(0, houses.size()) .boxed() .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> houses.get(i).getType(), terms::get, BinaryOperator.minBy(Comparator.comparing( Document::getRate))) .forEach((type,doc) -> System.out.println("type="+type+", "+doc));` Note that there’s no point in creating a `Map.entry` when the next step will be implicitly create `Map` entries anyway, further, using `toMap` instead of `groupingBy` avoids dealing with `Optional`.

Comment: Alex/Vincendep/Holger, .... Thank you for your initial input.  However I've reasons for setting up the structure explicitly.  GW I will elaborate in few days.  No rush.  In the meantime, would you please mind showing the output to a HashMap of Map<String, String> instead of println.  Thank you.